# USB wired Keyboard, scissor switch, non-chiclet, 100% with dedicated media keys, and anti-ghosting?

Tags: keyboards

I'm familiar with the Cherry Stream (and will probably get one), and it matches my desired specs for everything but that it's *not anti-ghosting*.  Is there any anti-ghosting keyboards with all of these other traits?

- Full size (100%)
- Scissor Switch
- Non-chiclet bevelled keycaps (ThinkPad style) with low travel
- Anti-ghosting
- Dedicated media keys
- ANSI layout
- Wired

I've looked for the right keyboard for years but with the steamroll of mechanicals, it's hard to find other kinds of boards. There was an old keyboard that I was married called the BenQ x700, and I had two of them, but they were both wireless variants and both broke in different ways.  Such keyboards are discontinued and hard to find.

Comment: Oof yeah that's a tough set of requirements; the Cougar Vantar almost meets this, but it has chicklet style keycaps and no media controls. Would you be open to low-profile mechanical switches? There are tons of low profile switches these days which will get you short travel and highly tactile actuations, they just aren't technically scissor switches. Most of these will be a bit thicker than you'd want in a laptop, but since I'm guessing this is for a laptop, I'm thinking that shouldn't be an issue?

Comment: If that is an issue, Cherry also makes the MX Ultra Low Profile switches, which are no thicker than traditional scissor switches but are fully mechanical. Unfortunately the only non-laptop keyboard I'm aware of that uses them, the Cherry KW X ULP, has chicklet keycaps and no media keys (though it meets the other requirements.) If budget isn't an issue, you could create your own keyboard using these switches. Especially with QMK/VIA, that's not a ridiculous concept these days, though it will be a good amount of work.

Comment: I'm a pretty avid hater of the sound and feel of mechanical switches honestly, as well as always cringed whenever regular slotted dome keyboards had plastic scraping on plastic or getting stuck because of not pushing the key down perfectly perpendicular.  The rubber "bump" has always been perfect (like on tv remotes etc), and i don't understand the move away from them.

Comment: There's a lot more range in the mechanical keyboard switch market these days than even a few years ago; if you're okay with a slightly taller keyboard, I'd encourage you to at least try the [Sunset Tactile Choc](https://lowprokb.ca/products/sunset-tactile-choc-switches) switches; they're low profile, have a strong tactile bump, and are very quiet. If anything with the name "mechanical" on it is a dealbreaker, you could also try the Microsoft Sidewinder X4; it's an older rubber-dome gaming keyboard with NKRO and dedicated media keys, but they're not scissor switches.

Comment: I've looked around at stuff like ex [Ergopedia](https://www.ergopedia.ca/ergonomic_concepts/Tactility_on_Keyboards_How_to_Evaluate_Soft_or_Light_Touch.html), and found the tactile feedback of scissor switches to be very strongly unique, and not something that really replicates in other forms.  It has the S curve of a membrane but it's much shorter and sharper; and the actuation is simultaneous with the end of the bump (it throws the actuator at the contact for you).  Mechanical switches always have odd and complicated travels.  Building mech keyboards from switches tends to be quite expensive.